# Haskell - Not in scope: class Gen

Tags: haskell

In the main module we have:

```
import System.Environment
import System.Random

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    random <- choose (0,100000) :: Gen Int
    newCards = baralhar (mkStdGen random) baralho40
    putStrLn $ "-----The End -----"
```

and we get this error when we compile:

```
Bisca.hs:13:36: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Gen’
   |
13 |     random <- choose (0,100000) :: Gen Int
   |                                    ^^^
```

I don´t understand what the Gen means and what the solution could be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoogle reports that `choose` is a function from QuickCheck (see [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=choose)). `Gen` is a type from [`Test.QuickCheck.Gen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.10.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html).

You just need to add an `import` statement for the QuickCheck library (`Test.QuickCheck` and `Test.QuickCheck.Gen`) and make sure your build system is aware of the library.

Comment: That's not the only problem here. In fact, the code looks pretty much completely bogus.